# AS3 xml loop shows many times

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have this simple code to play with xml

```
var testXML:XML = <family>
                  <father name1="tom" age="5" ></father>
                  <mother name1="tomylee" age="55" ></mother>
                                  <sister name1="sister1" age="35" ></sister>
                  </family>;

for each(var element:XML in testXML.elements()) {
                    trace(element.@name1);
                }
```

It should get only one output like

```
tom
tomylee
sister1
tom
tomylee
sister1
tom
tomylee
sister1
```

and many more like that. Looks like it keeps repeating. The croll bar keeps moving down.
I think loop is not stopping

Comment: is this code by any chance inside another infinite loop?

Comment: i have only one loop that is for loop. no other loop in program

I am executing the code by ctrl + ENter in Flash.
DO i need to add any line to stop executing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this code in a frame script? If you have more than one frame on your timeline, flash will play through them in sequence and repeat, by default. You can use the `stop()` command to stop playback on the current frame, or if you only put a single frame in the timeline, it will only execute once.